# How to write re direct url for my old site

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a web site and it's built in PHP. Now I'm going to transfer my website to Wordpress. I want to redirect my all post URL to new URL.
Below is the one example for old site URL and new site URL

and i have more than 15000 url to redirect.

Old

```
www.test.com/test-3-15348-4.html
```

New

```
www.test.com/test-new-collection
```

Comment: You'd need to write the following in your .htaccess: 
RewriteRule ^test-new-collection/$ test-3-15348-4.html

Answer (score 0):

As soon as, from what you have written, the URLs are completely different, you'll need to make it manually via PHP

PHP Redirect

```
header("location: www.test.com/test-new-collection");
```